# hotpatch wheels repair kit

Tags: wheels

i am a trapper and I use hot patches to fix my waders  but I have not been able to find anywhere to buy them. Do you know of a distributor in the ohio area that sells them or can I order them.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Unfortunately this type of a question is off topic due to asking about shopping assistance. You might find [what you need here](http://www.patchrubber.com/tire_repair/14208.html), though.